# Usage multithreading could lead to excessive memory use

Tags: c#, multithreading, service

I'm having a windows service project that logs messages to a database (or other place). The frequency of these messages could go up to ten per second. Since sending and processing the messages shouldn't delay the main process of the service I start a new thread for the processing of every message. This means that if the main process needs to send 100 log messages, 100 threads are started that process each message. I learned that when a thread is done, it will be cleaned so I don't have to dispose it. As long as I dispose all used objects in the thread everything should be working fine.

The service could go into a exception that leads to shutting down the service. Before the service shuts down it should wait for all threads that were logging messages. To achieve this it adds the thread to a list every time a thread is started. When the wait-for-threads method is called, all threads in the list are checked if it is still alive and if so, it uses join to wait for it.

The code:

Creating the thread:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Creates a new thread and sends the message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logMessage"></param>
    private static void ThreadSend(IMessage logMessage)
    {
        ParameterizedThreadStart threadStart = new ParameterizedThreadStart(MessageHandler.HandleMessage);
        Thread messageThread = new Thread(threadStart);
        messageThread.Name = "LogMessageThread";            
        messageThread.Start(logMessage);
        threads.Add(messageThread);
    }
```

The waiting for threads to end:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Waits for threads that are still being processed
    /// </summary>
    public static void WaitForThreads()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Thread thread in threads)
        {
            i++;
            if (thread.IsAlive)
            {
                Debug.Print("waiting for {0} - {1} to end...", thread.Name, i);
                thread.Join();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now my main concern is if this service runs for a month it will still have all threads (millions) in the list (most of them dead). This will eat memory and I don't know how much. This in whole doesn't seem to be a good practice to me, I want to clean up finished threads but I can't find out how to do it. Does any one have a good or best practice for this?

Comment: Have you considered using a `ThreadPool` or `Tasks`?

Comment: I have looked into threadpool, but it is seemed to be overkill for what I want, tasks are still unknown to me. Could you tell me why I should consider it? Which functionality that I might need do they have?

Comment: A `ThreadPool` managed thread creation and destruction for you. So you don't need to manage this yourself. Have a read of the article I linked in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately we're using .net 3.5, so no support for tasks. I'm looking into threadpool now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since multiple answers and comments led to my solution I will post the complete code here.

I used threadpool to manage the threads and code from this [page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8398/Wait-for-threads-in-a-ThreadPool-object-to-complet) for the wating function.

Creating the thread:

```
private static void ThreadSend(IMessage logMessage)
        {    
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MessageHandler.HandleMessage, logMessage);
        }
```

Waiting for the threads to finish:

```
public static bool WaitForThreads(int maxWaitingTime)
        {
            int maxThreads = 0;
            int placeHolder = 0;
            int availableThreads = 0;

            while (maxWaitingTime > 0)
            {
                System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out maxThreads, out placeHolder);
                System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out availableThreads, out placeHolder);

                //Stop if all threads are available
                if (availableThreads == maxThreads)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
                --maxWaitingTime;            
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Optionally you can add this somewhere outside these methods to limit the amount of threads in the pool.

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MaxWorkerThreads, MaxCompletionPortThreads);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the threads from the list if they are dead?

```
/// <summary>
/// Waits for threads that are still being processed
/// </summary>
public static void WaitForThreads()
{
    List<Thread> toRemove = new List<int>();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (Thread thread in threads)
    {
        i++;
        if (thread.IsAlive)
        {
            Debug.Print("waiting for {0} - {1} to end...", thread.Name, i);
            thread.Join();
        }
        else
        {
            toRemove.Add(thread);
        }
    }
    threads.RemoveAll(x => toRemove.Contains(x));
}
```

Have a look at [Task Parallelism](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C)

Comment: Since WaitForThreads is only called when the service kind of crashes, it doesn't matter anymore at that point. I need to keep it clean while running the service.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Creating one thread per log message is *not* a good idea. Either use `ThreadPool` or create a limited number of worker threads which handle the log items from a common queue (producer/consumer).

Second: Of course you need to also remove the thread references from the list! Either when the thread method ends, it can remove itself, or you can even do it on a regular basis. For example, have a timer run every half and hour that checks the list for dead threads and removes them.

Comment: I'm slowly drowning into the swamp of threading but I was wondering why not just replace everything in method ThreadSend with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MessageHandler.HandleMessage, logMessage); And use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8398/Wait-for-threads-in-a-ThreadPool-object-to-complet) for the waiting. Would that be sufficient/efficient?

Comment: Using the `ThreadPool` is almost certainly more efficient than using one single thread for each log message.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing in those threads is logging, you should probably have a single logging thread and a shared queue that the main thread puts messages on. The logging thread can then read the queue and log. This is incredibly easy with the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

Create the queue in the service's main thread:

```
BlockingCollection<IMessage> LogMessageQueue = new BlockingCollection<IMessage>();
```

Your service's main thread creates a `Logger` (see below) instance, which starts a thread to process log messages. The main thread adds items to the `LogMessageQueue`. The logger thread reads them from the queue. When the main thread wants to shut down, it calls `LogMessageQueue.CompleteAdding`. The logger will empty the queue and exit.

Main thread would look like this:

```
// start the logger
Logger _loggingThread = new Logger(LogMessageQueue);

// to log a message:
LogMessageQueue.Add(logMessage);

// when the program needs to shut down:
LogMessageQueue.CompleteAdding();
```

And the logger class:

```
class Logger
{
    BlockingCollection<IMessage> _queue;
    Thread _loggingThread;

    public Logger(BlockingCollection<IMessage> queue)
    {
        _queue = queue;
        _loggingThread = new Thread(LoggingThreadProc);
    }

    private void LoggingThreadProc(object state)
    {
        IMessage msg;
        while (_queue.TryTake(out msg, TimeSpan.Infinite))
        {
            // log the item
        }
    }
}
```

This way you have just one additional thread, messages are guaranteed to be processed in the order they're sent (not true of your current approach), and you don't have to worry about keeping track of thread shutdown, etc.

### Update

If some of your log messages will take time to process (the email you described, for example), you can process them asynchronously. For example:

```
while (_queue.TryTake(out msg, TimeSpan.Infinite))
{
    if (msg.Type == Email)
    {
        // start asynchronous task to send email
    }
    else
    {
        // write to log file
    }
}
```

This way, only those messages that potentially take lots of time will run asynchronously. You can also have a secondary queue there if you want, for the email messages. That way you won't get bogged down with a bunch of email threads. Rather, you limit it to one or two, or perhaps a handful.

Note that you can also have multiple `Logger` instances if you want, all reading from the same message queue. Just make sure they're each writing to a different log file. The queue itself will support multiple consumers.

Comment: this looks like a very neat solution, but I there is a small but very important detail in my question: the "Other place". Logging could also go to an email server, or to a file. This depends on the type of log message (e.g. big failures will be emailed as well). This other thing could take some time, and meanwhile new logs should be processed and it shouldn't wait for the email server. I don't care about the sequence, that will be ordered with the logmessage.date property.

Answer (score 0):

I think in general the approach to solve your issue is maybe not the best practice. 
I mean, instead of creating 1000s of threads, you just want to store 1000s of messages in a database right? And it seems you want to do this asynchronously.

But creating a thread for each message is not really a good idea and actually does not solve that issue...

Instead I would try to implement something like message queues. You can have multiple queues and each queue has its own thread. If messages are coming in, you send them to one of the queues (alternating)...

The queue either waits for a certain amount of messages, or always waits a certain amount of time (e.g. 1 second, depends of how long it takes to store e.g. 100 messages within the database) until it tries to store the queued messages in the database.
This way you should actually always have a constant number of threads and you shouldn't see any performance issues...

Also it would enable you to batch insert data and not only one by one with the overhead of db connections etc...

Of cause, if your database is slower then the tasks are able to store the messages, more and more messages will be queued... But that's true for your current solution, also.